# Файл заголовков С++ в Линуксе

Tags: g++, c++, linux

Всем привет.

Предстоит проект в С++. Писаться он будет под Линукс. Хоть и знаю его неплохо -но это было давно, вот читаю уроки - вспоминаю.

Столкнулся вот с чем - вот код простенькой программы:

```
#include <iostream.h>
int main()
{
       std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
       return 1;
}
```

в терминале набираю:

```
user@debian:~/Documents/cpp$ g++ -o sample sample.cpp
```

но компилятор ругается:

```
sample.cpp:1:22: error: iostream.h: No such file or directory
sample.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
sample.cpp:4: error: ‘cout’ is not a member of ‘std’
sample.cpp:4: error: ‘endl’ is not a member of ‘std’
```

правлю код - убираю .h из обьявления заголовка и работает.

Почему так?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Потому что такого заголовочного файла (iostream.h) нет. Но есть iostream. С ним все работает как нужно. По стандарту, большинство заголовков идет без .h

Это же не чистый С.

Comment: гмм... понятно. Спасибо.

Comment: Да, причем это не зависит от Линукса или Мака или Виндов. Любой нормальный компилятор будет себя так вести.

Вы раньше на чистом С писали?

Comment: писал ещё под Борландским компиляторе под Дос. Кстати пример взят отсюда - http://www.intuit.ru/department/pl/cpp/1/2.html

Comment: ну для этого компилятора, когда он только дос приложения делал - это было нормально. Лучше пользуйтесь сайтом [cplusplus.com](cplusplus.com). Там много справочной информации и она достаточно в ногу со временем. Она правда на английском, но это же справочник - синтаксис подсмотреть, правильные функции.

Comment: спасибо за наводку. Хотел что-то русскоязычное - но на безрыбье...

Comment: @KoVadim: лучше [_не_ пользоваться](http://stackroulette.com/programmers/88241/undefined) cplusplus.com. Я бы посоветовал [cppreference](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp), там и русский есть :)

Comment: к сожалению, я не знаю идеальных сайтов. тот же ru.cppreference.com имеет очень веселые страницы на русском с текстом "This page has been machine-translated from the English version of the wiki using Google Translate.". Заходим к примеру на [эту](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef) страницу и видим

>> становится ЬурейеЕ-имя, а чем объект

Comment: @KoVadim: по крайней мере, английская часть сайта лучше. Ну и разработчику надо знать английский, вся документация на нём.

Comment: Но Вы же сами написали "там и русский есть":))
а примерять мозг всегда нужно.

Comment: @KoVadim: исправил :-D

Comment: @alexlz: так вы бы и написали, внизу ж поле для ответа. И автору вопроса понятнее будет с двумя объяснениями.

Answer (score 2):

Грамотеи, блин. Написали бы просто, что был и iostream.h, но давно, а теперь такое уже не носят (кроме тех, кто использует древние компиляторы).

Стандарт появился году в 95м, а до того были Страуструп I (первая редакция -- ещё без template'ов) и Страуструп II. Некогда популярный BC++ v3.1 (не говоря уж про Трупный C++ v1.0, на котором была написана знаменитая Wing Commander, впоследствии WC I) появился до стандарта.